# Set audio current time using Google VR Audio Engine in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cardboard, google-vr

I am using google VR audio engine to play an ambisonic audio in my iOS app

```
audioEngine = [[GVRAudioEngine alloc] initWithRenderingMode:kRenderingModeBinauralHighQuality];

[audioEngine preloadSoundFile:url];
[audioEngine start];

ambisonicid = [audioEngine createSoundfield:url];
```

I am able to play/pause the audio and rotate it but I also want to change the audio current time when I change the time of my video.

Is there anyway I could do it with google VR API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked in the github repo and it is not possible yet.

The link for the issue: [How to get/set audio current time with GVRAudioEngine?](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-ios-sdk/issues/155)